# Amplifier and speaker compatibility?

Tags: amplifier, speakers

Will this [amplifier](https://www.banggood.com/nl/1002-HIFI-2x100W-TPA3116-AUX+-bluetooth-5_0-HIFI-High-Power-Digital-Amplifier-Stereo-Board-AMP-Amplificador-Home-Theater-p-1652632.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN) work with these [speakers?](https://www.bol.com/nl/p/e-audio-b402c-inbouw-luidspreker-set-28-cm-180-watt/9200000096356106/?bltg=itm_event%3Dclick%26mmt_id%3DX4axJTBSPEGQE6P9HGsxNQAABkM%26slt_type%3Drecommendations%26pg_nm%3Dpdp%26slt_id%3Dprd_reco%26slt_nm%3Dproduct_recommendations%26slt_pos%3DC1%26slt_owner%3Dccs%26itm_type%3Dproduct%26itm_lp%3D1%26itm_id%3D9200000096356106&bltgh=rAVj6DXfuRGf9tugWfdFvw.1_8_9.10.ProductTitle)

Answer (score 1):

If you click around both sites enough, you will find the information needed to figure out if the speakers and amplifier will work together.

Amplifier:

- 2X 100 watts - that's two outputs rated for 100 watts each.
- Rated for speaker impedance 4 to 8 ohms.

Speakers:

- Rated power 180 watts each.
- Impedance 8 ohms.

The impedance matches.

The speakers are rated for more power than the amplifier can provide.

By the ratings, it should be safe to use the selected speakers with the selected amplifier.

---

Neither source is known for high quality products or adequate documentation.

You may find that the 180 watt rated speakers are "peak music power output" or other marketing waffle words and can only stand 5 watts continuous and will blow when exposed to an amplifier that can provide 100 watts continuous.  Or the reverse may be true:  The amplifier is 100 watts "peak music power output" but only 5 watts continuous, in which case the speakers will not be very loud.

When buying cheap crap from questionable sources, you assume responsibility when it fails.

But from a reputable source with reliable datasheets and pay more money, or buy from cheap places and pay more in effort and risk.